# How do i change the src of an html5 video via javascript without either crashing chrome or leak memory?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-video

I'm working on an application running on Chrome only.

I need to be able to switch the source from a playing video.

I've used javascript (&jQuery) to change the `src` attribute :

```
$fullscreenVideo.get(0).src = '/video/' + name + '.mp4'; // crash here
$fullscreenVideo.get(0).load();
$fullscreenVideo.get(0).play();
```

It works a few times but my chrome (tried beta & dev channels) ends up crashing (page become unresponsive).

If i try to create a new element prepending last codeblock with :

```
$fullscreenVideo.remove();
$fullscreenVideo = $('<video id="video-fullscreen" width="800" height="600" loop="loop"></video>').appendTo("#page-fullscreen > div.fullscreen");
```

Every video switch increase RAM by 20Mo without ever getting back down.

Is there a way to trace/prevent chrome crash en src update ?
Is there a way to force free memory ?

Comment: What happens if you run `load` and don't run `play`? Maybe it needs a delay before the play...?

Comment: It crashes on the src attribute update, before load or play. I tried to add some delay before it but did not change anything.

Comment: What if you add a `.src=''` first, to clear it?

Comment: I tried it, with or without 150ms delay timeouts, it seems to crash less often, but it still crashes. I'll try to tweak timeouts to see if it can be crash free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been the same problem.
I read in some foruns that is a chrome's bug with memory leaks (some people say that just happens in chrome 8 and in chrome 6 works fine, but i didn't test it).

I also read that using a sleep helps. I tried and it is true, if i put a sleep before change url atribute and call load() the crashes number decreases. But still continues to crash after many changes.

Then, i tried to use setTimeout (unlike sleep, it doesn't bloq CPU, leaving it free to chrome's work).

And it is working now.
Try to see if my code helps.

```
var videoChangingPending = false;
function changeMovieSource(url, title){

        var $video = $('#video');
        try {
            document.getElementById('video').src = url;
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }     

        $video.attr('autoplay', 'true');
        $video.data('currentTitle', title);

        document.getElementById('video').load();

        videoChangingPending = false;
}    

function startPlayer(url, title) {

        if(videoChangingPending == true) 
            return;



        document.getElementById('video').pause();


        videoChangingPending = true;
        var changeMovieCallback = function(){ changeMovieSource(url, title);}
        var t = setTimeout(changeMovieCallback, 800);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I hated all these answers because they were too short or relied on other frameworks.

Here is "one" vanilla JS way of doing this, working in Chrome, please test in other browsers:

http://jsfiddle.net/mattdlockyer/5eCEu/2/

HTML:

```
<video id="video" width="320" height="240"></video>
```

JS:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var source = document.createElement('source');

source.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.tools4movies.com/trailers/1012/Kill%20Bill%20Vol.3.mp4');

video.appendChild(source);
video.play();

setTimeout(function() {  
    video.pause();

   source.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.tools4movies.com/trailers/1012/Despicable%20Me%202.mp4'); 

    video.load();
    video.play();
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume the first way should work fine, and Chrome's `<video>` implementation is still buggy. Feel free to mention it on their bug report forums.

Comment: +1 I agree it must be a bug, but still would be nice if anyone knew a workaround

Comment: Unfortunately I don't, I haven't had a need for video tags yet. But the sooner you mention it on their site, the faster it will get fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this problem so all I did was remove the video tag and then add another with the current url "on the fly".

Comment: but in that case, your ram does not leak?